# Matlab Confusion Matrix has a 0% for a class during training

Tags: matlab

When I train MLP using Matlab for 6 classes, for one of the classes I get a 0% in GREEN in the confusion matrix. This leads to to a high error percent for the overall training, validation and testing. 
What is the cause for this and how may I resolve this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Try asking this on Cross Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, give some extra details.

Comment: Are you sure that you have GREEN samples in your training dataset?

Comment: Yes.. There are green samples